# Get reverse relationship for item in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have a list (QuerySet of 'DailyEnrollment' objects) of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[
{'location_id': 1, 'student_count': 780}, 
{'location_id': 4, 'student_count': 535}, 
{'location_id': 6, 'student_count': 496}
]
```

There is a `Location` object which has an attribute `name` - the `location_id` in this list, correlates to a `Location` object but it is *not* a foreign key (in the models) due to how other apps interact with this in our project.

Is there a simple way to iterate across this list, get each dictionaries `location.name` for the `location_id` and append it to the dictionary as `location_name`?

I was considering a dictionary comprehension inside of a list comprehension - but I wasn't sure how Pythonic that was.

Models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The DailyEnrollment is data nabbed from a view built with external data

```
class DailyEnrollment(SchoolModel):
    id            = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    location_id   = models.IntegerField(db_column='schoolID')
    grade         = models.CharField(db_column='grade', max_length=10)
    end_year      = models.IntegerField(db_column='endYear')
    run_date      = models.DateField(db_column='runDate')
    student_count = models.IntegerField(db_column='studentCount')
```

In the view this is how I get my Daily Enrollments

```
# get past enrollments
    past_daily_enrollments = DailyEnrollment.objects.filter(
                run_date=datetime.strptime(since_date, '%m-%d-%Y'),
                location_id__lte='31',
                end_year='2018')
```

I create a 'new list' of data with everything grouped on `location_id`, with the total `student_count`

```
location_data = past_daily_enrollments.values('location_id').annotate(
    student_count=Sum('student_count')
)
```

That's how I get to the issue I asked about. I have 'location_data', which is my list of dictionaries.

Comment: Is this written in Django?

Comment: This question is incomplete. Provide (samples of) all the necessary data structures and the desired output.

Comment: You should be able to fetch the `Location.name` with the QuerySet you are already getting. Let me know if you want to know how to do this instead.

Comment: @Tobias that would be great! I just wasn't sure how to go about getting those `Location` names with that QuerySet - I can always append those results.

Comment: @timgeb - I updated with additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So (for the time being) I went about manually reconciling them through a few steps.

First I use my location data and get a list of all the ID's like this:

```
location_ids   = [s['location_id'] for s in location_data]
```

Then I get the Location objects for those ID's:

```
location_items = Location.objects.filter(
        id__in=location_ids
    )
```

Then I make a small dictionary with the ID and the name:

```
location_names = [
        {'location_id':s.id, 'location_name': s.name}
        for s in location_items
    ]
```

Then I chain the two lists of dictionaries together and and create a new one from them based on the 'location_id' tying each dictionary together.

```
additional_location_data  = defaultdict(dict)
for d in chain(past_enrollments, location_names):
    additional_location_data[d['location_id']].update(d)
```

This worked to reconcile the location_id with the name of the Location object and put the name in a dictionary (inside of a list) in the appropriate spots.

It's probably fairly 'ugly' for now - but I'll worry about cleaning it up later.

Answer (score 0):

Your models are not correct. I suspect that they were produced by running `inspectdb` against an existing database; one of the issues with doing that is that it is occasionally unable to detect foreign keys. In your case however, `location_id` is clearly a foreign key to Location, so you should declare it as such:

```
location = models.ForeignKey('Location', db_column='schoolID')
```

Once you have done that, you can simply follow the relationship via the double-underscore syntax in your values call:

```
past_daily_enrollments.values('location__name')...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the scope of this application (there are multiple apps at play here), the models are correct.  I see now that `location_id` is not a direct FK relationship. I'll make changes to my question.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information then. If `location_id` is not the ID of a Location object, then what is it? And how are you expecting to get to the relevant Location?

Comment: While it's not a direct FK relationship in the models due to the limitations we have in place, the `location_id` *does* match the primary key for the appropriate Location item. So I've had to manually reconcile them because I don't think there's a real "Django" way to get that relationship otherwise (because no relationship exists in the models).